# IE Uncaught ReferenceError: jQ is not defined, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, referenceerror

I get an

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQ is not defined
```

in the Internet Explorer and some tabs aren't being loaded.

But using Chrome it works perfectly fine.

I think it's because the script order for jquery might be wrong. This is what I have in my `startpage.js`

```
<script src="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquery/v2_1_4/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/tools/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/tools/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/tools/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid_5_3_0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/tools/jqgrid/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/apps/cpc.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/scripts/apps/3rdParties/startPage3rdParties.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/Scripts/tools/date.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquerymap/dist/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tools/Scripts/tools/jquerymap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
```

In this `startpage.js` I define `jQ` like this:

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

In a function `loadSubtables()` I call some functions from `gridhandling.js`:

```
function loadSubTables() {

    if (checkNull(curuserid) == "") {
        curuserid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    }

    loadGrid("AKG", "&$select=Id,Title,Projektstichwort,SD_x002d_Nummer,AKGStatus,Created,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/WorkPhone&$expand=Author&$filter=Author eq " + curuserid + " or Projektleiter eq " + curuserid +"&$orderby=Id desc", "gridmy", cnMyEntries, cmMyEntries, true, false);
    loadGrid("AKG", "&$select=Id,Title,Projektstichwort,SD_x002d_Nummer,AKGStatus,Created,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/WorkPhone&$expand=Author&$filter=AKGStatus eq 'Aktiv'&$orderby=Id desc&$top=9999", "gridactive", cnMyEntries, cmMyEntries, true, false);
    loadGrid("AKG", "&$select=Id,Title,archivFlag,Projektstichwort,SD_x002d_Nummer,AKGStatus,Created,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/WorkPhone&$expand=Author&$orderby=Id desc&$top=9999", "gridall", cnAllEntries, cmAllEntries, true, false);          
}
```

The error I get refers to this line from the `gridhandling.js`:

```
function loadGrid(listname, query, divname, colnames, colmdodel,showSubGrid,subGridFunction) {

    jQ("#" + divname).jqGrid({
```

I checked if jQuery is loaded, which it is, but since 5 hours I can't figure out what the problem is and how to fix this bug. Sometimes it doesn't load anything and just says `jQ( “#tabs” ).tabs(); is not a function`

Can someone help me?

Comment: _"This is what I have in my startpage.js"_ - Why do you have markup in a `*.js` file?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry what do you mean with markup?

Comment: `<script>` is markup. It doesn't belong in a JavaScript file which should contain JavaScript code only.

Comment: Which version of IE? The 2.x branch of jQuery removed *a lot* of support for legacy and outdated browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan IE 11

Comment: @VLAZ It's just a comment. It's not being used, but used as a reference to know whats going on

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, I have created a web page with two javascript file, based on your description, I define a variable in the first .js file, then access it from the second .js file, it works well on my side. You could try to clear the browser data (cache, browser history and so on), then, recheck whether it works well or not? If still not working, can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem?